# Rails multi-shard: how to have a job hit a specific shard

Tags: jobs, sharding, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm using the Rails 6.1 feature of horizontal sharding, and it works great.

I'm using the notion of having the subdomain route to the right shard, so my multi_db.rb config looks like:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.active_record.shard_selector = { lock: true }
  config.active_record.shard_resolver = ->(request) {
# I only have 2 shards, primary (english) and one in spanish:
    return request.subdomain == "es" ? "spanish": "primary"
  }
end
```

If I hit some URL such as: `es.mycompany.com`, the code will correctly route to the "spanish" shard. If I hit `mycompany.com`, it'll just go to the primary.

But now I have a job that wants to run in a particular shard. As far as I can tell the above code doesn't get called when a job is run, and it makes sense given the "request" arg; it looks like it's only invoked per request to some controller.

But with jobs, there is no controller involved, so how does one "hook in" shard selection for a job?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be fairly straightforward:

```
def perform(shard)
  ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(shard: shard) do
    # Job code
  end
end
```

This assumes you know the shard when you kick off the job (which is my case).